“Invalid reference to 'this' expression.” How can I fix it？（newbie）
Here's the code
enter image description here
@override
StatelessElement createElement() => StatelessElement(this);

class Echo extends StatelessWidget  {
  const Echo({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    this.backgroundColor = Colors.grey, //默认为灰色
  }):super(key:key);

  final String text;
  final Color backgroundColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        color: backgroundColor,
        child: Text(text),
      ),
    );
  }
}
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Echo(text: "hello world");
}

Here are the results
enter image description here
lib/main.dart:128:54: Error: Expected identifier, but got 'this'.
StatelessElement createElement() => StatelessElement(this);
                                                     ^^^^
Failed to compile application.


I copied the code from the book.But it didn't work.

Ig you are trying to create StatefulWidget

You need to put your code within a class declaration.
